# Error compiling Rails 3 CSS asset on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

We're getting the following error on random page loads:

```
Error compiling CSS asset
Encoding::ConverterNotFoundError: code converter not found (US-ASCII to UTF-16BE) (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/master.css)
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.10/lib/sass/util.rb:494 in 'encode'
```

Rails 3.1 app running on the Bamboo stack. I've never seen this error locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Rails 3.1 pipeline, you need to switch to cedar.

From [Heroku documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar):

> While Rails 3.1 can run on the Bamboo stack without the asset
>   pipeline, Rails 3.1 runs best on Heroku’s Cedar stack.

Your error seems to be related to an Encoding error in the CSS file. I suggest you to open your file and check the encoding is UTF-8.