# Assets don't seem to be compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I keep getting the error saying that the application.css isn't compiled.

I tried:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

And it didn't work, I even tried to run it with RAILS_ENV=production and still it didnt' work.

When I change my production.rb and set the config.assets.compile = true then it worked.

WHy isn't the manual compiling working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great RailsGuide on the Asset Pipeline:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

you need to set RAILS_ENV before running "precompile", e.g.:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

See also:

[rake assets:precompile doesn't work (rails 3.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845585/rake-assetsprecompile-doesnt-work-rails-3-1-1)

[Rails 3.1 asset precompilation - include all javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278029/rails-3-1-asset-precompilation)

Comment: I would also check that the settings in your config files match the defaults in the last section of the guide.