# bundle exec rake assets:precompile fails with `unexpected token`

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-3.1, web-deployment

I'm ready to deploy my Rails 3.1 app into production, and since I'm using the asset pipeline, [I need to precompile my assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production).  However, when I try this, I get an error apparently related to compiling jQuery:

```
$ bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby /home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
399: unexpected token at '"/*!\u000a * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.7.1\u000a * http://jquery.com/\u000a *\u000a * Copyright 2011, John Resig\u000a * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.\u000a * http://jquery.org/license\u000a *\u000a * Includes Sizzle.js\u000a * http://sizzlejs.com/\u000a * Copyright 2011, The Dojo Foundation\u000a * Released under the MIT, BSD, and GPL Licenses.\u000a *\u000a * Date: Mon Nov 21 21:11:03 2011 -0500\u000a */\u000afunction addActiveScaffoldPageToHistory(a,b){if(typeof
```

[snip lots of stuff]

```
  (in /data/music/RotC/eventbook/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/json-1.6.4/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/json-1.6.4/lib/json/common.rb:148:in `parse'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json/engines/json_common.rb:9:in `decode'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/multi_json-1.0.4/lib/multi_json.rb:76:in `decode'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:61:in `extract_result'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:27:in `block in exec'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:40:in `compile_to_tempfile'
/home/adam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails-3.1/gems/execjs-1.2.13/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:26:in `exec'
```

[snip lots more stuff]

Here's my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//
// N.B. jQuery requires have to come before this:
//= require active_scaffold
```

I'm using the default compressor, i.e. `uglifier`.

I've found that if I change `config.assets.compress` to `false` in `config/environments/production.rb` then it works fine, but of course my app would perform better if I could figure out a way to keep it as `true`.

I've looked at [rake assets:precompile doesn't work (rails 3.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845585/rake-assetsprecompile-doesnt-work-rails-3-1-1) and I don't think it's a duplicate because the error is `undefined: Unexpected token: operator (<)`.

Any ideas?  I'm vaguely suspicious of those unicode characters in the jQuery code, but I'm not sure how to prove or disprove that they are causing the problem.

Comment: which js compressor are you using? What's in your application.js?

Comment: Question now updated with these.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had this **exact** same problem and solved it, here are the details:

When you include one or more javascript files in your Rails 3.1 environment using application.js and `//= require ...`, Rails will wrap the contents of your file with a `<script> ..filecontents.. </script>`.  You can verify this by running your site in development mode and doing a View | Source.

The problem is, in development mode, if you are *not* actually using that script, it may *appear* to work fine.  But, Essentially, what you have is `<script><script> ..filecontents.. </script></script>`.

However, when you attempt to PRECOMPILE the assets, something in that compiling process (sorry - I do not know what exactly) gags on the "<" in the inner script token.

Double-check your included .js files and, if any of them are wrapped by `<script> ... </script>` remove those surrounding tags.

You should see that, in Development, everything still looks fine if you View Page Source.  And, when you precompile your assets, the error should go away.

I ran into this problem with Google's recommended google-analytics javascript snippet and removing the script wrapper from the included file solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to report this, Dave.  Actually at some point since asking this question, the issue magically fixed itself for me - perhaps due my upgrade of Rails to 3.2 or one of the gems?  However I'm accepting your answer because it sounds like a plausible solution for people still seeing the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I came across this in rails 3.2. Super helpful!

Comment: did not solve my problem (i have no script tags except the `application javascript include tag in application.html.erb`

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks so much. I resolved my problem when one of my gems includes `html` file which has invalid <script> tab.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but my unexpected token was `>`. Turns out I was writing ES6 in an app that didn't support ES6.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I debugged this.

Locally, run this

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Try to find out where it chokes (the script right before the choking is the file you'll want to look at). Look at all the requires.

In my case, I had a file that ended in `.js` when it should've been `.jsx` and that's what fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem.

Even though I did not have a `<script>` tag in my javascript files, Dave's suggestion helped me a lot!

I was able to spot a comment on a external lib I was loading in my `application.js`:

`<!-- Hotjar Tracking Code for (...) ->`

That single comment was breaking my `uglifier` compression and it took me a long time to find it and even possibly think it was the culprit.

So, also **watch out for comments in the begining of JS files,** as the might break your compression.

Comment: If you want to put comments in your JavaScript, use `/* */` or `//`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That came from `hotjar` embedded code, which some dev copied when it added hotjar.