# Unexpected token : operator (<) when pushing to heroku (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

for some reason I am getting a really weird error when pushing to heroku.

```
    rake aborted!
remote:        ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token: operator (<) (line: 14451, col: 2, pos: 408763)
remote:        Error
remote:        at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at js_error (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at croak (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at token_error (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at unexpected (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs...)
remote:        at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs...)
```

and does anyone know what the `line: , col: , pos:` represent?

are there any files that you need to see?

Comment: *does anyone know what the line: , col: , pos: represent?*  The location of the error in the source code.

Comment: yes, but how do I interpret it?

Comment: "Please go to line 14451 and look around for '<'.  If not found there, look at the previous lines."

Comment: haha yeah, but where is that located? I have no line 14451 in my code... how do i find that log?

Comment: Unless `ExecJS::ProgramError:` is something in your code, then the error is in the *heroku* source code.  Do you have '<' anywhere in your code?  Check all those lines for errors.

Comment: I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854057/bundle-exec-rake-assetsprecompile-fails-with-unexpected-token

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with webcomponents-lite.min.js. It looks as though heroku requires a new line at the end of the file.

As the entire file was on one line. I added a new empty line, i.e. went to the end of the file and pressed return.

Commit and pushed to heroku - problem solved.